# Referências podem afetar a performance?

Tags: c#, compiladores

No C#, por exemplo, posso referenciar diversos `namespaces`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Text;
```

O próprio `Visual Studio`, a partir da versão 2015, se não me engano, mostra quais dessas referências não estão sendo usadas, esmaecendo elas.

Durante o desenvolvimento devo me preocupar com isso e remover as referências que não estão sendo utilizadas de certas classes? Ou o próprio compilador já faz isso de alguma forma?

Entendo que a performance de execução do meu código não será afetada, já que não utilizo a referência, correto?

Mas com isso posso gerar `DLLs` desnecessárias ou até deixar as DLLs do meu projeto maiores prejudicando o desempenho de alguma forma?

Existem diferenças em outras linguagens e que possam requerer mais atenção?